# Finding if journey passes near certain address/location?

Tags: gis-principle

I am thinking to create a website where people can share car journeys. Users can register a car journey and other users can find a journey.

At the moment, when a user registers a journey, I save the starting and ending **`lat & lng`** of that journey in a database table called `journeys`. Other users can search a journey by entering their source and destination postcodes (postcodes a mapped to their lat and lng).

How can I know if a certain journey passes near the user searched destination postcode?

For example, a journey starts from location `A` and ends at location `C` but it passes location `B`. A user wants to find a journey from `A` to `B`.

Comment: Unless you store more than start and finish, you have zero knowledge about the in-between. They might have taken a detour to the north pole.

Comment: You are right, but I think it is impossible to save every point or location that the journey is going through? do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You probably need to look at route traveled and it's proximity to point `B`